# Protégé 5.2.0: How do I define a class name that includes the space character?

Tags: ontology, protege

I’ve experienced firsthand how Protégé automatically replaces any spaces with underscores when defining class names. But at the same time, I’m able to open particular ontologies (e.g. [BFO 2.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BFO-ontology/BFO/master/releases/2.0/bfo.owl)) in Protégé that do appear to contain class names defined with spaces. This fact raises my hopes that there is some way to use Protégé to define class names with spaces in them after all. If so, how? If not, then what is a suitable workaround?

For example, I found the BFO class name 'generically dependent continuant' appears to contain spaces.

[image: BFO URI with spaces example.]

Comment: Please give an example of URI with spaces in BFO. Probably you have rendering by rdfs:label enabled.

Comment: Play with *View > Render by...*. Look into ontology source.

Comment: Pointers much appreciated. In the end, I was able achieve my objective by typing a class name with spaces into the rdfs:label field of an already defined class without spaces in the name.